# Why is this string being converted to BigDecimal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am debugging a rails app for my boss while he is on vacation. We have an app the company uses that we can use to fill out timesheets and view customer tickets. On the open tickets page, there is a column with a brief description of the ticket. We have an environment on Ubuntu for production, and an XP environment for development, both of those don't experience the bug. But if I run the environment on Windows 7 or newer, the description doesn't show up as a string but as a BigDecimal, usually as "0.0" some of the tickets show other numbers. I would post screenshots but I won't for the privacy of the company.

Here's what I know so far: The database we are using displays the actual description in the table. The view and controller are both explicitly converting to string, when I got rid of `.to_s` in the code, the bug persisted. I have the class type being sent to a logfile as well that confirms it is a BigDecimal. When running the production code from my machine the bug persisted. I think it is an OS compatibility issue possibly. Or somewhere between the database and the app itself, the data is being converted to BigDecimal in a file that I don't yet know about. I am running rails 3.0.7 and ruby 1.9.2p290

Here is the code I think is suspect:

```
    <div id="page_center">
    <div id="branding_row">
        <%= label_tag("Show_Open", "Show Open Tickets",{:class => 'page_label'}) -%>    
    </div>


    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <% @locationHash.keys.each  do |keyItem| %>
                <li><a href="#tabs-<%= keyItem %>"><%= keyItem %></a></li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
        <% @locationHash.keys.each do |keyItem| %>          
            <div id="tabs-<%= keyItem %>">
                <table >
                    <tr >
                        <th style="width:50px; empty-cells:hide;">WO#</th>  
                        <th style="width:125px; empty-cells:hide;">Customer Name</th>
                        <th style="width:125px; empty-cells:hide;">Description</th>    
                        <th style="width:65px; empty-cells:hide;">Tech</th>    
                        <th style="width:125px; empty-cells:hide;">Date/Time</th>       
                    </tr>
                    <% @locationHash[keyItem].each do |ticketItem| %>
                        <tr>
                            <td><%= ticketItem.work_order.to_s  %></td>  
                            <td><%= ticketItem.customer_name.to_s  %></td>    
                            <td><%= ticketItem.woDesc.to_s  %></td>    
                            <td><%= ticketItem.tech.to_s  %></td>    
                            <td><%= ticketItem.created_at.to_s %></td>      
                        </tr>
                    <% end %>
                </table>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>  
<div id="right_column">
</div>
```

Here's the controller:

```
class TicketsController < ApplicationController
    def populate_workOrders
        @customerId = params[:customerID]
        logger.debug "@customerId = #{@customerId.to_s}"
        @tickets = Ticket.where(:customer_id => @customerId)
        logger.debug "@tickets size = #{@tickets.size.to_s}"

        @outputTickets = Array.new

        @tickets.each {|ticketItem|
            #select only tickets with specific open/usable codes
            if ['ARV','CAN','COM','D','H','O','S','PERM','CB','CN'].include?( ticketItem.woStatus )
                logger.debug "workorder - #{ticketItem.work_order} status - #{ticketItem.woStatus}"
                @outputTickets << ticketItem
            end
        }



        respond_to do |format|
            format.json { render :json => @outputTickets.to_json }
        end
    end
    def show_open
        logger.debug "******   inside Tickets - show_open   ******"
        @customersHash = Hash.new
        @locationHash = Hash.new
        @tempTicketArray = Array.new



        # @customers = Customer.all
        # logger.debug "@customers size = #{@customers.size.to_s}"

        # @customers.each {|customerItem|
            # @customersHash[customerItem.id] = customerItem
        # }


        ## updates names
        # @allTickets = Ticket.all

        # @allTickets.each{|ticketItem|
            # ticketItem.customer_name = @customersHash[ticketItem.customer_id].name 
            # ticketItem.save
        # }



        @tickets = Ticket.where(woStatus: ['ARV','CAN','COM','D','H','O','S'])
        logger.debug "@tickets size = #{@tickets.size.to_s}"

        @tickets.sort_by!{|y| [y.work_order]}.reverse!

        @tickets.each {|ticketItem|
            logger.debug "#{ticketItem.customer_name.to_s } + #{ticketItem.woDesc.class}"
            if @locationHash.has_key?(ticketItem.office) 
                @locationHash[ticketItem.office] << ticketItem
            else
                @locationHash[ticketItem.office] = Array.new
                @locationHash[ticketItem.office] << ticketItem
            end     
        }   

        @locationHash.keys.each {|keyItem|
            logger.debug "#{keyItem} array size = #{@locationHash[keyItem].size.to_s}"
            @locationHash[keyItem].each{|ticketItem|    
                    logger.debug "#{ticketItem.customer_name.to_s } - #{ticketItem.woDesc.class}"

            }
        }
    end
end
```

Here is schema.rb with irrelevant parts ommitted:

```
create_table "customers", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "number"
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

create_table "entries", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "customer"
    t.string   "work_order"
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "arrival_time"
    t.string   "depart_time"
    t.integer  "day_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "timesheet_order"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.boolean  "submitted"
    t.integer  "ticket_id"
    t.integer  "customer_id"
    t.integer  "type_id"
    t.integer  "productivityType"
  end

create_table "ticket_import", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
    t.string "srvStat"
    t.string "offId"
    t.string "callNbr"
    t.string "custName"
    t.string "priorityLevel"
    t.string "svcDescr"
    t.string "techId"
    t.string "endDte"
    t.string "custNum"
  end

create_table "tickets", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "work_order"
    t.integer  "customer_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "woStatus"
    t.string   "office"
    t.text     "woDesc"
    t.string   "tech"
    t.string   "entDate"
    t.string   "customer_name"
  end
```

Comment: There isn't by any chance a `.to_f` floating around anywhere is there?

Comment: @ChaseGilliam I have been searching for `.to_f` and `.to_d` in the view and controller and haven't found any.

Comment: Can you post the schema section for TicketItem? And maybe the controller action that loads this view?

Comment: @ChaseGilliam can you clarify what you mean by schema section for TicketItem? I posted the tickets controller.

Comment: the section of Schema.rb that defines the attributes for Tickets.

Comment: @ChaseGilliam I have added the relevant schema.rb parts

Comment: Bizarre. Ok, well you definitely don't need to use `.to_s` on any of those things in your view. I'm guessing you have a case where `woDesc` is `nil`... and nil is being coerced somehow on Windows. Its hard to say for sure as rails 3.0.7 and ruby 1.9.2p290 are both quite old now :(

try checking for nil in the controlled and setting `woDesc = woDesc || ""` or something like that. GL.